# Adding Function to String.Prototype

Tags: javascript

While reading [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/), I encountered this code on partial function application:

```
String.prototype.csv = String.prototype.split.partial(/,\s*/);

var results = ("Mugan, Jin, Fuu").csv();

console.log("results:", results);
```

But, when I tried to run it in jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Tv4/), I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function split() { [native code] } has no method 'partial'

How can I add the `csv` function to the `String.Prototype`?

Comment: See here http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

below is the code to execute this method and referece taken from @elclanrs given url good one bro.
Check out this FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Tv4/1/

```
    Function.prototype.partial = function(){
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function(){
      var arg = 0;
      for ( var i = 0; i < args.length && arg < arguments.length; i++ )
        if ( args[i] === undefined )
          args[i] = arguments[arg++];
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
  };

String.prototype.csv = String.prototype.split.partial(/,\s*/);

     var results = ("Mugan, Jin, Fuu").csv();
 console.log(results);
```